# How to put a transparent view on another Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I am working on Surface view. I want one transparent view on my surface view. That transparent view must consist of three things Title, Description and Spinner and one button name "Start". Without entering the title, description and Spinner's menu one cannot go the next layout which is below that transparent view. Please help me to with some sort of examples.. How to achieve such kind of view??? This is what I want.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84tN1.png)

This is My Surfaceview layout..

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/suface_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <net.ossrs.yasea.SrsCameraView
        android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need the useless LinearLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  // Add other view

 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/suface_view_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">


  <net.ossrs.yasea.SrsCameraView
    android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Man... Its works... I took one FrameLayout (A) in which I put those 4 things and I took one FrameLayout (B) just like you said for my cameraview.. and I simply included  Layout A in Layout B and got the desire result... Thank you sooo much..

Comment: One more question.. How to dismiss Layout A after checking if the title is valid or not??? Suppose I put title and after button click I want to disable that layout and switch to Layout B??

Comment: You can do using view `Visibility`.just set visibility `GONE`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/suface_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <net.ossrs.yasea.SrsCameraView
                android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <view 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLauout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can place FrameLayout



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


or You can place View


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</View>



 </RelativeLayout>

 FrameLayout is the better option
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RelativeLayout or FrameLayout you can put another layout above the SurfaceView,to make the layout as transparent to make the below SurfaceView partially visible,We have to set alpha to the background color of the layout.We can make a particular color transparent through changing the color code.

Normally color codes will be in this format,

**RR   GG   BB      or       R     G     B**

Eg:     **# ff    00      00      or    # f      f      0**

Which tells the Green Blue Red values from **0** to **f** (Hexadecimal)

We have one more color code format to set alpha values to change a color's opacity,

**AA  RR   GG   BB      or      A   R     G     B**

Eg: **# ff    ff    00      00      or    #0      f      f      0**

Which tells Alpha Green Blue Red values from 0 to f (Hexadecimal)

So to make any color transparent we can vary the value of alpha from 0 to f.
For example: Consider we want to make black color as transparent,

Color code of black is `#000000`,to make it transparent change it to

- `#00000000` - Fully Transparent
- `#88000000` - Partial transparent
- `#ff000000` - No transparency

Set this color to your layout to make it transparent.